# Why does my PBR material appear grey in game?

Tags: materials, jmonkeyengine, pbr, kotlin

I am playing around with PBR materials and I cant get them to work correctly. When I create a material using PBR the model appears gray in game. Any ideas on why I’m not getting the same result?

```
val floorMaterial = Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Light/PBRLighting.j3md")
floorMaterial.setTexture("BaseColorMap", assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/Floor_Diffuse.png"))
floorMaterial.setTexture("NormalMap", assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/Floor_Normal.png"))
floorMaterial.setTexture("SpecularMap", assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/Floor_Specular.png"))
val sun = DirectionalLight()
sun.color = ColorRGBA.White.mult(1.3f)
sun.direction = Vector3f(-.5f, -.5f, -.5f).normalizeLocal()
main.rootNode.addLight(sun)
val lightProbe = LightProbe()
lightProbe.position = Vector3f(0f, 10f, 0f)
addLight(lightProbe)
```

[image]

For comparison when I use regular lighting this is the result

```
val floorMaterial = Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Light/Lighting.j3md")
floorMaterial.setTexture("DiffuseMap", assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/Floor_Diffuse.png"))
floorMaterial.setTexture("NormalMap", assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/Floor_Normal.png"))
val sun = DirectionalLight()
sun.color = ColorRGBA.White.mult(1.3f)
sun.direction = Vector3f(-.5f, -.5f, -.5f).normalizeLocal()
main.rootNode.addLight(sun)
val lightProbe = LightProbe()
lightProbe.position = Vector3f(0f, 10f, 0f)
addLight(lightProbe)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it working with a prebuilt light cube. https://github.com/Simsilica/Spix/tree/MaterialEditor/proto/assets/Probes